# setImage or setTitle ..only one is working in segmented Control iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

When i was trying to develop an app using segmented control with 4 buttons It is unable to set both title and image.For each one i have set an image.And when i am trying to set an title for each one instead of image title is replacing.How to use both image and set a title just below the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A segment can only have an image or a title; it can’t have both. There is no default title.

Comment: not in the normal way, BUT you have a couple of options. One is to loop through the segmented control's subviews and investigate each view and add an imageview inside every segment - i think this way you can achieve having a title and a image together. The other one is to search for custom segment controls, you can take a look [here](http://cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=segmented)

Comment: ok thank you..graver I think they will work I got a easy one that is I edited the image and add a title below the image and simply use the image to the segmentedcontrol